# Once event fired even if I `$.unbind('event')` all handlers fire. Is there a way to prevent event handlers firing, after event occured?

Tags: javascript, jquery, events, event-handling

I am prototyping mechanism that allows for additional modules to subscribe to main events of our framework and using array of deferred passed with event (convention) to control the flow of logic.

If the example below there are 4 event handlers that subscribe to event, if one of deferred is being rejected whole mechanism should terminate execution.
Currently to prevent event handlers (that would be modules plugged in) from executing I am at the top of each of handlers checking if

```
!$.grep(options.deferredArray,function(item){return item.state() == "rejected" }) == 0;
            if (hasRejected) return false;
```

**Once event fired even if I `$.unbind('OnPreRender')` all 4 handlers still fire. Is there a way to prevent that from happening, after OnPreRender occured?**

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Qxm2Y/)

```
var globalDeferred = $.Deferred(function(){setTimeout(function(){ console.log('%cglobal deferred','color : blue');}, 0)});
    var deferredArray = [globalDeferred.promise()];
     dataRoles.on('OnPreRender', function (e, options) {
     var hasRejected = !$.grep(options.deferredArray,function(item){return item.state() == "rejected" }) == 0;
        if (hasRejected) return false;
        var d = $.Deferred();
        options.deferredArray.push(d.promise());
        var rand = Math.floor(Math.random()*1000);
        setTimeout(function(){
        console.log("(1) in "+rand+" ms");
            d.resolve();
        },rand);
        return $.grep(options.deferredArray,function(item){return item.state() == "rejected" }) == 0;
        });

        dataRoles.on('OnPreRender', function (e, options) {
        var hasRejected = !$.grep(options.deferredArray,function(item){return item.state() == "rejected" }) == 0;
        if (hasRejected) return false;
        var d = $.Deferred();
        options.deferredArray.push(d.promise());
        var rand = Math.floor(Math.random()*1000);
        setTimeout(function(){
        console.log("(2) in "+rand+" ms");
            d.reject();
        },rand);
        });

        dataRoles.on('OnPreRender', function (e, options) {
        var hasRejected = !$.grep(options.deferredArray,function(item){return item.state() == "rejected" }) == 0;
        if (hasRejected) return false;
        var d = $.Deferred();
        options.deferredArray.push(d.promise());
        var rand = Math.floor(Math.random()*1000);
        setTimeout(function(){
        console.log("(3) in "+rand+" ms");
            d.resolve();
        },rand);
        });

        dataRoles.on('OnPreRender', function (e, options) {
        var hasRejected = !$.grep(options.deferredArray,function(item){return item.state() == "rejected" }) == 0;
        if (hasRejected) return false;
        var d = $.Deferred();
        options.deferredArray.push(d.promise());
        var rand = Math.floor(Math.random()*1000);
        setTimeout(function(){
        console.log("(4) in "+rand+" ms");
            d.resolve();
        },rand);
        return $.grep(options.deferredArray,function(item){return item.state() == "rejected" }) == 0;
        });

        globalDeferred.reject();
        $.when.apply($, deferredArray).then(function () {
            console.log('%csuccess','color : green');
                },function () {
            console.log("%cfail","color : red");
                });
        dataRoles.trigger('OnPreRender', { deferredArray :  deferredArray});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will fix your problem. You can replace your unbind/off with this

```
e.stopImmediatePropagation();
```

jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/Grimbode/Qxm2Y/2/

Comment: You can see from console log all 4 are still firing

Comment: Yes, I just noticed. So I added this e.stopImmediatePropagation(); and there is only one now. Updating my post.

Comment: And just triple checked it, you can replace your unbind by e.stopImmediatePropagation(); , however gives (1) everytime now.